# Retrieving a value from a form using django dajax

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

I have the following model:

```
class Usage(models.Model):

    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    territory = models.ForeignKey(Territory)
    usage_in_month = models.ForeignKey(UsageInMonth)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.region
```

I have a modelform which I tried giving a name, class and id of project_form:

```
self.fields['usage_in_month'].widget.attrs['onchange'] = "Dajaxice.projects.update_usage_in_month(Dajax.process,{'option':this.value, 'current':this.id, 'form': $('project_form').serialize(true)})"
```

This goes through the ajax.py which contains:

```
@dajaxice_register
def update_usage_in_month(request, option, current, form):
    dajax = Dajax()
    form = ProjectForm(form)

    # As the first ID has no prefix current is shorter
    if current[:40] == 'id_usages-tvusage-content_type-object_id':
        current_short = current[:42]
        current_usage_in_month = '#' + current_short + '-usage_in_month'
        current_suggested_rate = '#' + current_short + '-suggested_rate'

    else:
        # Current is longer for other IDs
        current_short = current[:82]
        current_usage_in_month = '#' + current_short + '-usage_in_month'
        current_suggested_rate = '#' + current_short + '-suggested_rate'

    cpa_rate = UsageInMonth.objects.get(id=option).cpa_rate
    dajax.assign(current_suggested_rate,'value',cpa_rate)
    return dajax.json()
```

I have no problems with this. My issue is accessing the form prior to the return dajax.json() in order to retrieve a value from it. I have tried form.cleaned_data['territory'] as well as form.cleaned_data.get('territory'). I have tracked down the issue to the form being passed into the view via the form as it seems to be blank, so the

```
self.fields['usage_in_month'].widget.attrs['onchange'] = "Dajaxice.projects.update_usage_in_month(Dajax.process,{'option':this.value, 'current':this.id, 'form': $('project_form').serialize(true)})"
```

does not seem to be working

All I am trying to do is retrieve the value of one field not actually pass in the whole form but this is the only way I seem to be able to get the data I want. Is there a better way?